# Error (singularity) in the GRS test applied on portfolios that were used for constructing the Fama-French factors

Tags: asset-pricing, fama-french, econometrics

In the context of the Fama-French 3-factor model, we have six portfolios used for creating the SMB and HML factors: SL, SM, SH, BL, BM, BH. (The notation is: S~small, B~big, L~low, M~medium, H~high). If I use the six portfolios as test assets in the GRS test (with the three factors: market, SMB and HML), I get the following error:

```
Error in solve.default(sigma) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.02942e-17
```

I guess this is some sort of multicollinearity, given that the factors are linear combinations of the six portfolios. If so, could anyone provide some more detail or intuition on what is going on? If not, what is the issue?